# "Can't create Directory as the directory doesn't exist"

Tags: c#

This is my logging.cs, It usually may create the "Log-Folder" and the Datetime.csv into the users Desktop

```
public static class Logging
{
    public static string _Path = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\Logs\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.csv";
    static StreamWriter _File = new StreamWriter(_Path);

    public static void getPath(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }

    public static void logging(string message)
    {
        _File.Write(message);
    }
}
```

In my main class, i use the method logging just to enter "Test" into the csv file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logging.getPath(Logging._Path);
        Logging.logging("Test");
    }
}
```

but when there is no "Logs-Folder", i get the exception that part of the path doesn´t exist. If i create the path manually, i get the exception, that the path already exists, so something's wrong with the If-Statement up in the Logging-class. But i don't know what the heck works wrong

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Comment: you don't need to check if the directory exist. `Directory.CreateDirectory(path);` only creates the directory if it doesn't exist yet. You need to specify a valid path though.

Comment: You first should have read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2 then you need to understand the difference between a path and a filename. when you do this you will understand what the problem is and be able to solve it

Comment: To quickly get to the documentation of any method doubleclick it and press F1

Comment: view my answer with its output below might be it help you and if you find helpful then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :) –

Answer (score 4):

Your path is a file and not a directory. You need to create the directory from your path

```
    String Path = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\Logs\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.csv";

    String Directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path);

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Directory)==false) {
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory);
    }

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path)==false) {
      System.IO.File.Create(Path);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your _Path variable isn't actually a directory, but rather a filename.

You get the Directory with `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_Path)`

Answer (score 1):

Your testing if an Directory exists but your giving the path to a File. Here's some code you could use to fix it:

```
public static string _Path = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\Logs";
public static string _Filename = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.csv";
static StreamWriter _File = new StreamWriter(_File);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to take `DirectoryPath` and `FilePath` differently.

Move your `StreamWriter` to method scope so we can close this stream after `Write` content inside file.

```
public static class Logging
{
    public static string _DirectoryPath = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\Logs";
    public static string _FileName = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.csv";

    public static void getPath(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }

    public static void logging(string message)
    {
        StreamWriter _sw = new StreamWriter(_DirectoryPath + "\\" + _FileName);
        _sw.Write(message);
        _sw.Flush();
        _sw.Close();
    }
}
```

And from `Program.cs`.

```
Logging.getPath(Logging._DirectoryPath);
Logging.logging("Test");
```

**Output:**

[image]